# Enter x-value and find y-value in real data plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate, plot-themes

I have a plot based on real-world data. I want to make it possible, that the user can enter any value of x (enter manually or as dropdown or as slider) and the respective y value appears. At the same time, there should be a point, which jumps to the entered x-value.

The data I use is the following:

```
data = {{-96000, 1}, {-12949, 2}, {-4842, 3}, {-2222, 4}, {-735, 
   5}, {-81, 6}, {30, 7}, {187, 8}, {423, 9}, {816, 10}, {1194, 
   11}, {1561, 12}, {2097, 13}, {2720, 14}, {3268, 15}, {3833, 
   16}, {4538, 17}, {5042, 18}, {5555, 19}, {6165, 20}, {6839, 
   21}, {7660, 22}, {8418, 23}, {9290, 24}, {10241, 25}, {11205, 
   26}, {12089, 27}, {13077, 28}, {13945, 29}, {15332, 30}, {16691, 
   31}, {17994, 32}, {19368, 33}, {21034, 34}, {22470, 35}, {24308, 
   36}, {26118, 37}, {28138, 38}, {30701, 39}, {33409, 40}, {36651, 
   41}, {39924, 42}, {43709, 43}, {48337, 44}, {53194, 45}, {58966, 
   46}, {64870, 47}, {70386, 48}, {76917, 49}, {84542, 50}, {91719, 
   51}, {100206, 52}, {109028, 53}, {115236, 54}, {121209, 
   55}, {128617, 56}, {136466, 57}, {145436, 58}, {154077, 
   59}, {161558, 60}, {168802, 61}, {177820, 62}, {188075, 
   63}, {197551, 64}, {207513, 65}, {216346, 66}, {223449, 
   67}, {230092, 68}, {239571, 69}, {250742, 70}, {260915, 
   71}, {271182, 72}, {281361, 73}, {291735, 74}, {303973, 
   75}, {315228, 76}, {325877, 77}, {337903, 78}, {351584, 
   79}, {363072, 80}, {371321, 81}, {382482, 82}, {396815, 
   83}, {408623, 84}, {420767, 85}, {437121, 86}, {453049, 
   87}, {471017, 88}, {493422, 89}, {517036, 90}, {544031, 
   91}, {581599, 92}, {626884, 93}, {702909, 94}, {801905, 
   95}, {904205, 96}, {1074064, 97}, {1390025, 98}, {2013260, 
   99}, {14045856, 100}}
```

I plotted the data as follows:

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

I already tried this one, the slider looks good, but the plot does not work.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ListLinePlot[data, {lpd, 0, 10000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1000000}]], {Assets, 0, 1000000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: your plot does not work because `lpd` is undefined and after fixing that, the `PlotRange` is completely wrong. ( a single range is imposed on the vertical axis )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using `Interpolation` function. Read the documentation.

Answering what you asked, here's my solution:

Make the interpolation function:

```
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

In order to check how good the interpolation function is, plot f:

```
fPlot = Plot[f[x], {x, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}, 
           PlotRange -> Full];
```

[image: interpolation plot]

And Plot the original data:

```
dPlot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red];
```

[image: original data]

Here's how you compare them:

```
Show[{fPlot, dPlot}]
```

[image: comparison]

And to check the data with a slider:

```
Manipulate[N[f[x]], {x, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}];
```

[image: manipulate slider]

**Edit:**

Thanks to [@george2079's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172829/44854), I learned something new and put this code together. Check it out ;)

```
near = Nearest[data[[All, 1]] -> Automatic];
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[data, 
  Epilog -> {Inset[
     Text[Column[{"Nearest data = " <> ToString[data[[near[x], 1]]] <>
          ", " <> ToString[data[[near[x], 2]]], 
        "Current point = " <> ToString[f[x]]}]]], 
    Line[{{x, 0}, {x, f[x]}}], PointSize[.02], Point[{x, f[x]}], , 
    Pink, Point[data[[near[x]]]]}, PlotRange -> All], {x, 
  Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: post edit]

Comment: Thanks you so much. Looks like it is working. But is there a way how I can combine the slider and the interpolated graph?

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StudentsTDistributionAndItsNormalApproximation/

A perfect solution would be similiar to this t0 slider, so that the x-values and the area below the function has a colour, dependend on the slider

Comment: @MARIUS There you have it. Slider and the interpolated graph combined.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MARIUS You're welcome ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This highlights the actual data point closest to the user input via slider.

```
near = Nearest[data[[All, 1]] -> Automatic]
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> {PointSize[.02],
    Point[data[[near[Assets]]]]}, PlotRange -> All],
 {Assets, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```